# Prevent Spring from destroying connection pool on unload of war file

Tags: spring, tomcat, jdbc

While starting to utilize the 'version' capabilities of Tomcat I am finding that when Tomcat un-deploys a previous version of a war file Spring appears to be destroying the connection pool as well.   This is a problem because the other (newer) version of the app needs that connection pool

How do I prevent this?

Scenario:

1. Deploy ~/tomcat/webapps/helloworld##v1.war and start tomcat
2. HikariCP pool initializes properly
3. Users login
4. Deploy new version (~/tomcat/webapps/hellowworld##v2.war) via Tomcat Manager and Cargo
5. New users get v2 of war file.  Old users stay on v1 until sessions time out
6. Once all v1 sessions time-out Tomcat undeploys v1.
7. This is when the problem starts.  v2 can no longer get a DB Connection from JNDI

Datasources are setup in ~/tomcat/conf/server.xml as GlobalNameResources and referenced in each war file's context.xml

Comment: Remove the destroy method. So add `@Bean(destroyMethod="")` to your datasource lookup or `destroy-method=""` in XML.

Comment: That worked!   I am baffled why this wouldn't be the default behavior for spring (to NOT destroy the datasource) given all the major containers support sharing datasources across webapps as well as versioning of each webapp.

Please submit as an Answer so I can accept and you get the bounty

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 3.1 a feature called *destroy method inference* has been added to Spring. This was done with [SPR-8751](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/13393). What it does it takes a list of well-known destroy methods like `close`, `shutdown` (without arguments) and automatically adds that as a destroy method. Later this has been extended to also automatically detect implementations of the [`Closeable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html) (next to the method inference). This is mainly useful when auto-detecting components which need to receive a destruction callback.

As most `DataSource` implementations also implement [`Closable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Closeable.html), which defines a `close` method, it will automatically be destroyed when the application is undeployed. This is either done by detecting the `close` method (through reflection) or the fact that it is `Closeable`.

How to prevent the invocation of this method is mentioned in the [javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#destroyMethod--) (i.e add an empty `destroyMethod` (for Java Config) or `destroy-method` (for XML Config) to your bean definition. It is also explained in [the reference guide](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-java-lifecycle-callbacks) of the Spring Framework itself.